# Django Template does not exist in production server but is working in :8000

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi guys im having a problem with my own django server (at home), django can't find templates, my error code django is looking in the correct place (/var/www/project/templates) but nothing happen

**Template does not exist** but all path are fine.

but using test server :8000 all is fine, i dont know how ill fix this

**edit**

this is perfect for get the template:

```
/var/www/agricultura/templates/forms/registro_form.html
```

Template path

```
import os
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'templates'),
)

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/var/www/agricultura/templates/forms/registro_form.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/admin_tools/theming/templates/forms/registro_form.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/admin_tools/menu/templates/forms/registro_form.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/admin_tools/dashboard/templates/forms/registro_form.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/forms/registro_form.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader:



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/agricultura/registro/views.py" in registro_view
  71.                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  181.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  157.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  138.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /registro/
Exception Value: forms/registro_form.html
```

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Fixed: Permission problem :) now permissions are 777

Comment: You should not put your django code (even templates) in a directory that can is accessible by the browser. See [where should my code live?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 1):

Trivial, but I have seen instances where people forget to add the concerned application in the installed apps and get the template not found error.

Answer (score 0):

there might be an error in the template. Have you got TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True in the settings? And you've set TEMPLATE_DIRS as well?

Try loading the template via the python shell on your server:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

```
./manage.py shell
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', { 'foo': 'bar' })
```

It might throw an error and give you a further clue.

Comment: thanks pastylegs, but nothing news happen:
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
>>> rendered = render_to_string('indexHome.html',{'foo':'bar'})
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: indexHome.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings file:

```
def findMyWay(*relativeComponents):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *relativeComponents).replace("\\","/")

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    findMyWay("templates"),
)
```

Working perfectly fine for me.